# Events not displayed using jquery.timeline.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have set up a html page to display a timeline using jquery.timeline.min.js library.

I get the timeline displayed but no events are added to it.

Its the basic example given at the help page on the github of this library at https://ka2.org/getting-started/

What am i missing, my code is the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='dist/jquery.timeline.min.css'>

<script type='text/javascript' src='script/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='dist/jquery.timeline.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Timeline Block -->
<div id="myTimeline">
  <ul class="timeline-events">
    <li data-timeline-node="{ start:'2019-02-26 10:00',end:'2019-02-26 13:00',content:'<p>Event Body...</p>' }">Event Label</li>
    <li data-timeline-node="{ start:'2019-03-01 23:10',end:'2019-03-02 1:30' }">
      <span class="event-label">Event Label</span>
      <span class="event-content"><p>Event Body...</p></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- Timeline Event Detail View Area (optional) -->
<div class="timeline-event-view"></div>

<script> 
$("#myTimeline").Timeline();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make two changes.

1. initialize timeline inside jquery on-ready event.
2. set startDatetime of your timeline while initializing.

please see below

```
<script> 
$(function () {
    $("#myTimeline").Timeline({       
        startDatetime: "2019-02-25 00:00"   
    })
})

</script>
```

hope it helps.

thanks

Comment: now i get the events displayed, i just do not get them as individual events. i added rows = 5 but they are in one line see at www.2w.cl/gantt2